# Apache Ignite 2.13.0: problem with JVM memory settings

Tags: java, ignite, apache-httpclient-5.x

The idea is this: if I pass memory settings to the Apache Ignite JVM, I get strange errors.

There are a pair of servers, each running an Apache Ignite node. Ping between servers is 23ms.

We use Java 16.

There are several clients that are on the main server and run tasks in Apache Ignite cluster: `ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forServers()).callAsync(...)`.

These tasks access external APIs through a proxy using Apache HttpClient 5. A new proxy is used for each request. If an error occurs during the request - the proxy is not used for a minute, and the next proxy from the list is taken, as well. Three repetitions. The proxy has a limit of 100 requests per minute. All subsequent requests die by timeout. Apache HttpClient 5 settings have timeout limits. 3 seconds to connect and 10 seconds to get a response. If there are no proxies available, the task will sleep for 1 minute (`Thread.sleep(...)`).

In the previous version of Apache Ignite, we limited the memory used in the ignite.sh file: `JVM_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m"`.

In version 2.13.0, this code in ignite.sh is not executed because the JVM_OPTS variable already has some value by the time it is executed. Apparently, this is also the reason why the bug leaked into version 2.13.0:

```
if [ -z "$JVM_OPTS" ] ; then
    JVM_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m"
fi
```

I have carefully examined the arguments used to call the `org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup` class and found no difference other than the number of `--add-exports` and `--add-opens`.

In version 2.13.0, by default, the memory settings defined in the `ignite.sh` file are not transferred, although, in version 2.12.0, they were successfully applied.

When I forced the JVM_OPTS value to be initialized, I ran into a very strange error. After some time, usually it happens quite quickly, errors related to connecting to the proxy, `Read timed out` begin to arrive, the proxy queue becomes clogged and tasks begin to fall. The problem only occurs if two nodes are running. Moreover, on the main node, I can enable memory settings, the main thing is that they are not enabled on the second node.

If you carefully look at the logs on the second node, you can find the following:

```
[11:42:56,182][WARNING][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[4a6a3330 157.90.50.51:47500 crd]-#2-#45][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failing client node due to not receiving metrics updates from client node within 'IgniteConfiguration.clientFailureDetectionTimeout' (consider increasing configuration property) [timeout=30000, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9a85c6d4-bbfc-44e9-bbba-c60682f77795, consistentId=9a85c6d4-bbfc-44e9-bbba-c60682f77795, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 172.18.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /172.18.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=48, intOrder=27, lastExchangeTime=1654169823441, loc=false, ver=2.13.0#20220420-sha1:551f6ece, isClient=true]]
[11:42:56,183][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#56][GridDiscoveryManager] Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9a85c6d4-bbfc-44e9-bbba-c60682f77795, consistentId=9a85c6d4-bbfc-44e9-bbba-c60682f77795, addrs=ArrayList [127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 172.18.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/172.17.0.1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /172.18.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=48, intOrder=27, lastExchangeTime=1654169823441, loc=false, ver=2.13.0#20220420-sha1:551f6ece, isClient=true]
[11:42:56,184][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#56][GridJobProcessor] Job is being cancelled because master task node left grid (as there is no one waiting for results, job will not be failed over): 20664342181-9a85c6d4-bbfc-44e9-bbba-c60682f77795

[11:58:59,917][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#56][GridJobProcessor] Job is being cancelled because master task node left grid (as there is no one waiting for results, job will not be failed over): b20e3442181-c0ddaea8-7719-48ff-83df-6ac168ab5df4
```

You can also see the following errors: `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted`, this is interrupted tasks that have gone to sleep by `Thread.sleep()` because there are no proxies available.

That is, I can assume that the memory settings somehow affect the second node, it starts to slow down, which affects both HTTP requests to the proxy and the exchange of messages between nodes.

Running tasks die for two reasons:

1. The proxy queue is clogged, as a result of which the task "falls asleep" for a minute.
2. The second node decides that the master node is down and stops the task.

Simulating such a situation is quite difficult, and there is no way for me to publish the production code for testing. Therefore, it is quite possible that the solution to this problem will be delayed, if at all. But I will be glad to receive any suggestions.

**Updated 03.06.2022**

Rechecked version 2.12.0. There, in fact, memory management also did not work, apparently, the error has been going on since then. By the time `JVM_OPTS` is assigned the memory settings, this variable already has the value `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, so the value does not change - the memory settings are ignored.

```
if [ -z "$JVM_OPTS" ] ; then
    JVM_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m"
fi
```

But I remember exactly that in earlier versions of the project these settings worked, because we increased them to get rid of OutOfMemoryException.

The problem occurs if two servers work in conjunction and at least one of them has memory settings applied. Java 16. Ubuntu 18.

**Updated 06.06.2022**

According to Stephen Darlington, memory settings in the ignite.sh file have been ignored since at least 2020.

Comment: Are you editing the ignite.sh file in order to adjust memory settings?

Comment: I specify all the settings (node, logs, user libs, etc) for Ignite in another batch file. This simplifies updating Ignite, just delete the old version and write a new one in its place.

Memory settings from at least version 2.12 in the ignite.sh file are not applied unless manually edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug ([here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13404)) but it's always a good idea to explicitly set the memory parameters anyway. In your other batch file, if you set JVM_OPTS yourself, Ignite will take those values.

```
export JVM_OPTS="-server -Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:+UseG1GC"
$IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found how to configure the memory, but after these settings, our project became unstable. That is, if this is fixed in ignite.sh, then there is a chance that some of the projects using Apache Ignite will experience the same problems as ours. Until we find the reason, we will have to disable these settings and hope that the nodes do not consume all the server's memory.

Comment: "Hope" is not the right answer! Your Java heap space + data region size(s) has to be less than the total memory on your machine. If it's more than that, Ignite will start swapping to disk, which will cause instability.